# Python Threading Exception in thread Thread-2

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new in Threading,

I have a problem when I start 2 thread:

```
# Button starter with thread
        def button_starter():
            t = threading.Thread(target=button_start_command)
            t.start()

            # Button starter with thread
        def bmp_processor_starter():
            t = threading.Thread(target=bmp_processor)
            t.start()
```

when I click on GUI start button, one of them uses an AI framework based on tensor flow and the other is printing the obtained results...

error is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marko Jankovic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Marko Jankovic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:/Doktorske studije/2023/A_Company/Python/TempoCnn/dev_01.py", line 60, in bmp_processor
    self.tempo = self.classifier.estimate_tempo(self.features, interpolate=False)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tempocnn\classifier.py", line 133, in estimate_tempo
    prediction = self.estimate(data)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tempocnn\classifier.py", line 103, in estimate
    return self.model.predict(norm_data, norm_data.shape[0])
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 908, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 723, in predict
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 189, in model_iteration
    f = _make_execution_function(model, mode)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 566, in _make_execution_function
    return model._make_execution_function(mode)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2189, in _make_execution_function
    self._make_predict_function()
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2179, in _make_predict_function
    **kwargs)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3678, in function
    return GraphExecutionFunction(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3330, in __init__
    with ops.control_dependencies([self.outputs[0]]):
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 5254, in control_dependencies
    return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 4688, in control_dependencies
    c = self.as_graph_element(c)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3607, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "D:\Doktorske studije\2023\A_Company\Python\TempoCnn\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3686, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Activ10/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 256), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I am new in multithread!
I expect solutin for running without error!

Comment: Let's look at the stacktrace from top to bottom: first line is in multithreading, second line also, third line is in your code `bmp_processor`. The issue is not due to multithreading but to an error in your code. Do you also have the issue when you run it without the multihreading environment (and without the GUI) ?